# Jquery each display value of outside variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to display the value of a variable defined outside of $.each loop inside the loop. For eaxamle:

```
function fn(row, title) {
    var row = $(row);
    $.each(row, function() {
        var that = $(this),
            title = that.find(title);
    });
}

fn('.row', '.title');
```

When I console log the title variable inside each function I get undefined. is it possible to access that variable inside the loop?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand u. But do u mean u need to access the variable inside each function

Comment: Which variable are you trying to display?

Comment: the title which is passed as an argument to fn function. When I try to display it inside the loop I get undefined

Comment: If u want this u can use function (index,element) and then iside the function u can use $(element) instead of $(this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reassigning *title* with the result of the jQuery *find*:

```
title = that.find(title);
```

Maybe change it to:

```
var $title = that.find(title);
```

*$title* will now hold a jQuery object that you can do what you want with, and the original *title* won't change.

Comment: Also, `var that = $(this)` is useless, use `$(this).find(title)` instead of `that.find(title)`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. It works. So the problem was naming the variables inside the loop the same as the fn function arguments

Comment: Yes, most importantly you were actually reassigning title with another value. Usually good practice to regard parameters passed in as immutable.